# Update IEnumerable<XElement> and save changes in XML document C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, ienumerable

```
<OTPC>
  <OTPCDATA>
    <PROGRAM>LOT676-Q1T2-24 RevB @MC1 PVDB Version 3.8</PROGRAM>
    <TOTAL_QTY>54123</TOTAL_QTY>
    <PASS_QTY>60866</PASS_QTY>
    <FAIL_QTY>3257</FAIL_QTY>
    <FILE_DATE>7/29/2016 10:05:47 AM</FILE_DATE>
    <FILE_TIME>10:05:47</FILE_TIME>
    <STATUS>0</STATUS>
  </OTPCDATA>
....So On---
</OTPC>
```

Above is `XML` i need to modify and save changes in source document. There may be `Status=1` as well. I am filtering `XDocument` like below.

```
 XDocument unreadOTPC = XDocument.Load(pathToRead);
 var filteredOTPC = unreadOTPC.Element("OTPC")
                .Descendants("OTPCDATA")
                .Where(x => x.Element("STATUS").Value == "0");
```

It returns me `IEnumerable<XElement>`. I am updating Status using `filteredOTPC.ForEach(s=>)`

How do I update/Merge the modified `IEnumerable<XElement>` in Original `XDocument` instance and Save changes in `XML` source file.

Comment: So the question is, how to update the `status` element and save the document?

Comment: Yes, updated my question formatting ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"IEnumerable is separated from unreadOTPC"** is causing bit of confusion, if I understand the problem correctly, you need to update `STATUS` values in an `Xml` and save the document.

So, you could do this.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

var elements  = doc
        .Descendants("OTPCDATA")                       //flatten your hierarchy
        .Where(x=>(string)x.Element("STATUS") =="0")   // filter those elements whose nested status is  "0".
        .Select(x=>x.Element("STATUS"));               // Select those elements.
```

and Now you can update the element using any looping logic.

```
// Now update element value
foreach(var element in elements)
{
    // your logic.
    element.Value = "1";
}

doc.Save();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XqDQbM)

Comment: let me give it a try, Thanks for your prompt response

Comment: Thanks, I figured out I did not debug my code properly , I am accepting your answer.